# How to get startup arguments from Electron app?

Tags: command-line-arguments, electron

I'm building a React app, and wrapping it in an Electron build. 
So far, I'm able to create a working, stand-alone build.
Now, I want to add arguments to the launch:

```
open -a MyApp --args myName=One myVar=Two
```

As far as I understood, the process.argv gets extended with these arguments, but they don't appear in the argument array.

Does anyone know how to get this fixed?
I've searched the issues list from Electron, Atom and StackOverflow, but nothing so far...

Thanks!